# Gettext error while "make update-po"

Tags: makefile, gettext, autotools

I have followed this [guide](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/FAQ.html#integrating_howto), but when I try to do "make update-po" i get following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `update-po'. Stop.
```

Do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `configure`, does it tell you somewhere in its long list of output, that natural language support (NLS) is "enabled" or "disabled"? If disabled, then the makefile rules are also not output.